# Django 4.0.1 runserver with no issues pero no se puede acceder al sitio web

Tags: html, python-3.x, html5, django

Hace tiempo estaba realizando un proyecto en Django 4.0.1, el cual no ha tenido ningún problema o modificación, pero ahora que quise reanudarlo, no me es posible acceder a ningún template que tengo programado, tengo cómo 6 más el Admin, más la página de inicio, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi comando para iniciar el servidor:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes indicar el puerto, la ruta sería `127.0.0.1:8000` o `localshost:8000`. Los mismos logs de la consola indica que no se ha recibido ninguna petición, exactamente porque no visitas la página "real", que está en el puerto `8000` (por defecto es el `80`)

Comment: Se busca por "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" cómo lo dice textual en la consola, pero el resultado es lo mismo, pero tienes razón, en la consola no se refleja ningúna petición.